# how to configure vim to delete buffer after pressing ctrl-T?

Tags: vim

when using VIM we can jump to tags by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> . If the tag is in different source file
vim opens the file in a new buffer. But, when i return back to original position by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> the buffer of second file still exists.

Can we configure vim to auto delete the created buffers upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>?

Comment: I've wondered this myself but just sort of decided to live with it. I hope you get an answer.

Comment: I used to have a self-written script that would, on exiting a window or tab, check all window and tab filenames, deleting the buffer if it's the only/last viewport for the buffer. I'll need to rewrite it cuz I lost it, but if I ever get around to doing so I can post my solution.

Comment: Is there any benefit to deleting buffers?

Comment: @FDinoff we open some buffers for editing, and while understanding code we might jump to a tag and come back. These new buffers will clutter my list of existing buffers and hard to manage. I want to keep open only the buffers which i opened intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

You could work the problem out at one end with this mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-]> <C-]>:setlocal bufhidden=delete<CR>
```

or at the other end with this one:

```
nnoremap <C-t> <C-t>:bdelete#<C-r>
```